# PHP getting the value of a class variable on declaration

Tags: php, class

I'm just curious if it's possible to get the value of a class variable when making an object of it? What I'd like to do is:

```
$class = new MyClass("something")->ok;
```

For the example above, the class is:

```
class MyClass {
   public $ok;

   public function __construct($a) {
      $this->ok = $a;
   }
}
```

I know it's easy to get the value of `$a` by writing one more line, but I'm really curious if it's possible to do in a shorter way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. This feature is known as "Instance method call" and was [introduced in PHP 5.4](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). Just include a pair of extra parentheses wrapping the `new MyClass()` expression:

```
$class = (new MyClass("something"))->ok;
         ^                        ^
```

The expression `new MyClass()` is what returns the object (as opposed to the class constructor), which is why it requires to be wrapped in an extra pair of parentheses.

More reading:

- PHP RFC — [Instance Method Call](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/instance-method-call)
- Rasmus Lerdorf — [New Features in PHP 5.4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/lerdorf-php54-1564639.html)

Comment: So easy and clever solution, thank you! I used Class as the name of the class for example only, but I should've used something else, you're right. :)

Comment: @KissKoppány: Glad to have helped. Cheers!